# Right side of assignment cannot be destructured

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export type NavigationButtonProps = {
  linkTo: string;
  text: string;
  active: boolean;
  onClick?: () => void;
};

const NavigationButton = (props: NavigationButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <Link
      to={props.linkTo}
      className={props.active ? "decoration-accent underline decoration-4" : ""}
      onClick={props.onClick?.call}
    >
      {props.text}
    </Link>
  );
};

export default NavigationButton;
```

This code snippet is throwing the following error: `TypeError: Right side of assignment cannot be destructured`
(`The above error occurred in the <Link> component:`) The screen stays white, but when I remove the `<Link />` component it works as expected. `react-router-dom@^18.2.0` (latest) and `typescript@^5.0.3` (latest). Can someone please help me fixing this error?

Comment: `onClick={props.onClick?.call}` - Interesting way. I would write `onClick={() => props.onClick?.()}` instead and see if that fixes the error (probably not, but oh well).

Comment: Tried it out, sadly does not fix the error :/

Comment: I agree, I don't think you want to be immediately trying to invoke the callback. Why not just `onClick={props.onClick}`?

Comment: Okay, tanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me within a component which was outside of the router context. Which means you'd have to pass the Link component to NavigationButton from within the context.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).